# A computation with ramification groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to solve Exercise 3, Chapter 4, $\S 2$ of Local Fields by Serre.
The exercise is about ramification groups.

Let $L/K$ be a $p$-adic field extension with uniformizer $\pi$. Assume it is Galois with Galois group $G$. Let $e$ be the ramification index of $L$ over $\mathbf Q_p$. Take $s$ in the $i$-th ramification group $G_i$, $i \geq 1$, and denote by $a\in (\pi^i)$ the element such that $s(\pi) = \pi(1+a)$.

Knowing that $s(x)-x \equiv jax \pmod{\pi^{i+j+1}}$ for all $x\in \pi^{j}$, show that for all $x \in (\pi^j)$  and $i > \frac{e}{p-1}$ the following holds:
$$
  s^p(x) -x \equiv pjax \pmod{\pi^{i+j+e+1}}
$$
Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this? The book gives as a hint "use the binomial formula".

Comment: I don't know but denoting $s^p(x)-x$ as $(s^p-1).x$ then
$(s-1).\pi \in \pi^{i+1}O_L$ gives $\forall x,(s-1) .x\in x \pi^i O_L $, by induction $(s-1)^m.x\in x \pi^{im}  O_L$. There is some $z\in \Bbb{Z}[G]$ such that $s^p-1=(s-1)^p+pz$ and hence $(s^p-1).x= (s-1)^p.x+p z.x\in x\pi^{ip}O_L+xpO_L$

Comment: Yes, I tried that because it seems to me the only way to use the hint. The problem is that I don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write 
$$
s^p-1 = p (s-1) + p(s-1)^2 Q(s-1) + (s-1)^p
$$ 
for some polynomial $Q(T)\in \mathbb Z[T]$, and
notice that 
$$
p(s-1)^2 (x)= 0 \pmod{ \pi^{i+j+e+1}}.
$$

Comment: Ok, correct and I could finish the proof. Thank you!

Comment: I fill in the details. Using the identity, $(s-1)^p(x) = 0 \pmod{\pi^{i+j+e+1}}$ because $v((s-1)(x)) \geq v(x) +i$ and therefore $v((s-1)^p(x)) \geq ip + v(x)$ and the hypotheses imply that $ip+j \geq i +j +e +1$. Thus $(s^p-1)(x) \equiv p(s-1) \pmod{\pi^{i+j+e+1}}$ and the claim follows.

Comment: It was fun, thanks for the question!